# creating a sub/function that accepts various parameter values in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run SQL SERVER 2008 stored procedure using VB.NET. I am able to connect fine but I do not want to write the code over again for every stored procedure that I want to call. How can I have that code in form of a function or sub so that i can reuse the code by simply passing the stored procedure name to the code. Below is sample of what I am using.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Me.txtProcessDate.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter The processing Date Before You Continue ", vbOKOnly, "SMIS")
        Me.txtProcessDate.Focus()


    Else
        Try
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "computationsdelete"
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 6000
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            conn.Close()


            conn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "deductionssmoothing"
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 6000
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            conn.Close()


            MsgBox("RECORDS POSTED SUCCESSFULLY. YOU CAN NOW PRINT PAYSLIPS")

            conn.Open()
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", processdate)
            sqlcmd.Connection = conn
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            sqlcmd.CommandText = "insertpaymentsanddeductions"
            sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = 6000
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlcmd.Dispose()

            conn.Close()
```

Comment: Creating one function or sub would be senceless for all your db calls. You can but I would create a seperate class for your db calls with functions or subs than you can call them seperatly. This way you write the procedure once that takes your parameters. Also you may return a table, a scalar and so on if your wanting to return something. A function can only return one type which you may run into troubles unless your returning the same type always...

Comment: Many thanks, please help me derive an example using my code, I will be so grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably better doing something like @Codexer suggested in the comment on your question, but the code answer to your exact question is below.

```
Public Sub CallStoredProcedure(ByVal procedureName as String)
    ...

    cmd.CommandText = procedureName 

    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel, Please add more detail to your suggested code so that I can give it a try. Like how to use the sub for more than one procedure. Meanwhile I am also trying out @Codexers suggestion. It takes some time coz I am a little new to VB.NET

Comment: I created a class for dbcalls where i used the suggested code. On mouseclick event I added the following lines; Dim dbcall As New dbcalls                dbcall.CallStoredProcedure("computationsdelete")               dbcall.CallStoredProcedure("deductionssmoothing"). The challenge now is that some stored procedures require parameters. Do i need to create different subs for the procedures? OR is it possible to use a single sub for both parametized and non parametized procedures?

Comment: Nice work- great to see you were able to work it out :) 
Yes you can use a sub per procedure, however you can also use a single sub (at least by name) for both parametized and non parametized procedures. This is done by "Overloading" the subs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973896.aspx

You could make it so it is literally 1 sub, but Overloading is probably better for future code readability and extensibility. I made a pastebin as a demo: http://pastebin.com/ZRYUkwjy

Even with the same name it works by selecting the Sub with the same parameter Types.

Comment: Thanks @ Samuel, u b the best

Answer (score 0):

Here is some improvement that I made to my code when i created a separate class for db calls;

```
Public Sub searchifexists(ByVal value As String, ByVal table As String, ByVal field As String)
    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT " & field & " FROM  " & table & " where " & field & " = '" & value & "' "
    conn.Close()
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.Fill(dt)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Try
            MsgBox("Record already exists. Record will not be saved because you can not have duplicate values for Employee Number")
            Exit Sub

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

this is what I have on button click

```
    Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Try
        If btnAdd.Text = "&Revert" Then
            If EmpnoTextBox.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("You must enter a value for Employee Number")
                Me.EmpnoTextBox.Focus()
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf EmpnameTextBox.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("You must enter a value for Employee Name")
                Me.EmpnameTextBox.Focus()
                Exit Sub

            End If


            Dim dbcall As New dbcalls
            dbcall.searchifexists(EmpnoTextBox.Text, "employee", "empno")

            Save_Record()

            Change_Button(True)
            btnAdd.Text = "&Add"

        End If

        DisplayNav(sender, e)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
        MsgBox("Employee data saved")
    End Try
End Sub
```

From this I have learned to clean up my code, make it readable and have a better application. Thanks to the stackoverflow community!